# VERY messy data: How do I clean up horizontal data that is all inconsistent? [VBA]

Tags: excel, vba

I keep trying ways to fix a dataset, but keep running into problems because of how inconsistent it is.

Here's what the data looks like:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Entry1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Age | 45 | Occupation | Scientist | Phone Number | 408-283-3721 |  |  |
| User I.D. | 390842 | Housing Type | Condo | Square Footage | 1073.29 |  |  |
| Floors | 2 | Bathrooms | 2.5 | Budget Max | $289,287 |  |  |
| Household Size | 3 | Pets? | Yes |  |  |  |  |
| Entry2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Floors | 2 | Square Footage | 1974.19 | User I.D. | 379733 |  |  |
| Phone Number | 312-246-9121 | Pets? | No | Budget Max | $481,621 |  |  |
| Household Size | 4 | Bathrooms | 3 | Housing Type | Apartment |  |  |
| Occupation | Pilot | Age | 32 |  |  |  |  |
| Entry3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| User I.D. | 379621 | Floors | 1 | Square Footage | 1223.12 | Pets? | No |
| Occupation | Managing Director | Budget Max | $402,342 | Phone Number | 714-343-1358 | Household Size | 2 |
| Age | 31 | Bathrooms | 2 | Housing Type | House |  |  |

I want to create a new, cleaned dataset with headers along the top (e.g. "Age", "Occupation", etc) and the values associated (to the right of each variable name cell) as the row, underneath each column.

The variable names are all mixed up, not always on the same column or relative row, so it's not only transposing into a clean new dataset but finding the appropriate values depending on where the variable is (so, I'm thinking something like .Cells.Find(What:="the variable name") for each one and somehow returning the value next to it in a loop). Then, there's the issue where some entries have 3 rows and 8 columns and others 4 rows and 6 columns (not all rows being full too). I also struggle with placing the values under the appropriate column header and not replace the former value. (i.e not just changing one cell but adding to the one below and so on)

There are over 400 records like this, so doing it manually would be super tedious. I'm fairly certain these are all the variations though.

Comment: What have to tried so far?  You can use Match() against the header row of your cleaned-up table to locate the relevant column for each value entry.

Comment: Tried “text to columns”?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the data row by row.
If only the first column has data it is the header of an entry. Write that to a new workbook column A.

| Enrty Name |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Entry1 |  |  |  |  |  |

Then go to the next row. If more than 2 columns have data it is a data row to the previous entry. Data rows contain data in blocks of 2 cells, where the first block is the data description and the second cell the data value.
So you need to loop through the columns of the data rows in blocks of 2:

- Take the first block which is `Age | 45`
- Check if the column `Age` exists. Here it does not so we name the next free column `Age` and fill in the data to the last enty

| Enrty Name | Age |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Entry1 | 45 |  |  |  |  |

Then we move on to the next block `Occupation | Scientist` and do the same. Check if a column `Occupation` exists? No, ok insert next free column:

| Enrty Name | Age | Occupation |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Entry1 | 45 | Scientist |  |  |  |

We do this until the entire row is done, then we move over to the next one and if this is a data row too, we keep going until we find a new entry header.

So after the first entry your data would look like this:

| Enrty Name | Age | Occupation | Phone Number | User I.D. | Housing Type | Square Footage | Floors | Bathrooms | Budget Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Entry1 | 45 | Scientist | 408-283-3721 | 390842 | Condo | 1073.29 | 2 | 2.5 | $289,287 | Yes |

Then you move over to the next entry

| Enrty Name | Age | Occupation | Phone Number | User I.D. | Housing Type | Square Footage | Floors | Bathrooms | Budget Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Entry1 | 45 | Scientist | 408-283-3721 | 390842 | Condo | 1073.29 | 2 | 2.5 | $289,287 | Yes |
| Entry2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The first data set here is `Floors | 2`, so you search in the first row for `Floors` it is found in column 8. So we write `2` into column 8.

| Enrty Name | Age | Occupation | Phone Number | User I.D. | Housing Type | Square Footage | Floors | Bathrooms | Budget Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Entry1 | 45 | Scientist | 408-283-3721 | 390842 | Condo | 1073.29 | 2 | 2.5 | $289,287 | Yes |
| Entry2 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 |  |  |

If you keep that going you have cleaned up data in the end.

Answer (score 1):

If your real data corresponds to your example, where all the parameters are spelled identically, you can do this using Power Query.

*If there are variations in your data that this table doesn't show, examples of these variations would be needed to craft a better solution.*

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`

  - Select `My data does NOT have headers`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table name in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code** *(Modified to deal with missing Parameter Values)*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],

//Add grouping column Entries and Unpaivot
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Entry", each 
        if Text.StartsWith([Column1],"entry",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then [Column1] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Entry"}),

//Remove extra entry rows
remRows = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each [Entry] <> [Column1]),

//Table.ReplaceValue(#"Removed Columns1"," ",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Value"})

//Replace nulls with space so we don't lose one item of a "pair"
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(remRows,null," ",Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(remRows)),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Replaced Value", {"Entry"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Integer-Division" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Index], 2), Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Integer-Division",{"Index"}),

//Group in pairs
//Mark blank subTables
//Extract Entry, Parameter and Value
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns1", {"Integer-Division"}, {
        {"Empties", each List.NonNullCount(List.ReplaceValue(_[Value]," ", null,Replacer.ReplaceValue))},
        {"Entry", each _[Entry]{0}},
        {"Parameter", each _[Value]{0}},
        {"Value", each _[Value]{1}}
        }),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each ([Empties] <> 0)),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Integer-Division", "Empties"}),

//Group by Entry, Pivot and expand
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns2", {"Entry"}, {
        {"Pivot", each Table.Pivot(_, _[Parameter], "Parameter","Value")}
        }),

//Column name list for the Pivot table.
//Could sort or order them any way you want
colNames = List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns2"[Parameter]),

    #"Expanded Pivot" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows1", "Pivot", colNames,colNames)
in
    #"Expanded Pivot"
```

**Original Data**

[image]

**Transformed**

[image]